# Can't enable automatically renewable subscriptions

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I don't seem to have an option inside itunes connect to enable automatically renewable subscriptions. Are there some sort of requirements to enable it? I can't find much on it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have some contracts in pending in your iTunes Connect. 
Once you agreed on it you should find the relative option.
Also check that you set correctly your AppID.

Comment: `Check if you have some contracts in pending in your iTunes Connect. ` was the solution :) Thanks